# Multi tables relations in SELECT request

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table1.champs = table2.champs = table3.champs
```

And without any duplicate "champs" because at least one of the 3 tables should have duplicate lines.

Comment: What is a duplicate? How do Your tables look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use modern JOIN syntax instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
  JOIN table2 ON table1.champs = table2.champs 
  JOIN table3 ON table2.champs = table3.champs
```

Duplicated **rows** are removed with `SELECT DISTINCT`. If that's what you mean with "*without any duplicate champs*".

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN on your tables related fields

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.champs = t2.champs 
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.champs = t3.champs
```